# Remove double quotes from first line for all files in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 50 files in which column headers surrounded in double quotes on the first line. I want to remove the double quotes " from the first line for every file.

Can the changes be done in regular expression ??

Sample data.

```
"PRODUCTID","ATTRIBUTENAME_VALUE","STATE"
"00300678116042","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
"00041260363603","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
```

Expected output

```
PRODUCTID,ATTRIBUTENAME_VALUE,STATE
"00300678116042","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
"00041260363603","NOT_APPLICABLE","CONFIRMED"
```

Comment: with `sed` this will be trivial.  Do you have access to any unix toolset or cygwin?  For a single file `sed '1 s/"//g'` will do.  Or with `awk` you can do `awk 'NR==1{gsub(/"/,"")} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

If Notepad++ is Pcre compatible, you could

find:  `\G([^"\r\n]*)"`
replace `$1`

Answer (score 0):

If the column header is as provided, the below find and replace should work. You could specify the actual header names inside the parentheses. I used the fact that the header didn't contain any digits to uniquely identify the header row.

Find all: `\"(\D*)\",\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"`

Replace: `\1,\2,\3`